# how to display animation file in android

Tags: android, animation

I have an animation file that animates the logo and slogan of the company. Every application has a splash screen that flashes the animation along with the company name. I also want it to be done. Now I have a splash screen ready but I want an animation file to be displayed in the splash screen. What APIs of Android (XML and Java) both must I use? What is the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

See [Frame animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) (save your animation as distinct PNG files and make an XML describing how the PNGs should be linked)